# Creating an array without duplicates

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

My question is as follows. How to create an array with all the characters that were used in const char * pass in such a way that the array did not have any duplicates. For example:

```
const char *pass = "Qqqqqqqwwwww11111"
```

should create an array of

```
Q  |  q  |  w  |  1
```

Variable pass is given by the user, so it is difficult to determine how it gonna looks like.

Comment: This is very easy; what have you tried?  (Hint: `std::unordered_set<char>`.)

Comment: Is the array always guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: No, for example pass may looks like "Dma3q."

Comment: C++ have many nice [algorithms in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) or [`std::unique_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy).

Comment: Will duplicate characters always be consecutive?

Comment: @Zack i was trying to make 2 loops, but in beginner so its still hard for me.

Comment: @GWW Variable pass is given by the user, so it is difficult to determine how it gonna looks like.

Comment: Do you have a favorite container (e.g. array or std:vector or std:string)? Do you know how to iterate over the whole sequence? If you are iterating over the sequence, and your iterator is pointing to one element, do you know how to use another iterator to iterate over *the rest of the sequence*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to create an array without adjacent duplicate elements then at first you should count how many there are unique elements in string pass and then dynamically allocate memory for the array and copy unique elements in it.
The task can be simply done with using standard algorithms. For example

```
char *a = 0;

size_t n = std::strlen( pass );

if ( n != 0 )
{
    size_t count = 1 + std::inner_product( pass + 1, pass + n, pass, 0u, 
                                           std::plus<size_t>(),
                                           std::not_equal_to<const char>() );

    a = new char[count + 1];

    std::unique_copy( pass, pass + n + 1, a );
}
```

Or maybe it will be more simpler to write

```
char *a = 0;

size_t n = 1 + std::strlen( pass );

size_t count = 1 + std::inner_product( pass + 1, pass + n, pass, 0u, 
                                       std::plus<size_t>(),
                                       std::not_equal_to<const char>() );

a = new char[count];

std::unique_copy( pass, pass + n, a );
```

Answer (score 2):

One of many solution consists in using `std::sort` and `std::unique`. It's also simpler **and** safer to use `std::string` (or `std::vector`, ...).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    char *pass = "Qqqqqqqwwwww11111"; // or by user input

    // using std::string is easier and safer (works similarly with std::vector)
    std::string data(pass);

    // Remove duplicates with std::sort and std::unique
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    auto end = std::unique(data.begin(), data.end());

    // Remove duplicates – if needed.
    data.erase(end, data.end());

    // Print the unique chars
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on what you're doing, you might not need to `erase` the duplicate element of `data`. In this case, remember that `end` is an iterator on the first duplicate element (or, if the data has no duplicate in the first place, it's equal to `data.end()`).

NB: you absolutely need to sort your data before using `std::unique`.

[***Here you can try this code***](http://ideone.com/jrtBZh).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to remove all duplicates and order is imporatant, so [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) is not enough.

While your element type is small, like `char` - you can use `array`/`std::vector`/`std::bitset` to remember which elements have been met before:

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6afa08ca48e52d3)

```
template<typename I, typename O>
I remove_duplicates(I first, I last, O out)
{
    using T = typename iterator_traits<I>::value_type;
    using limits = numeric_limits<T>;

    constexpr auto min = limits::lowest();
    constexpr auto max = limits::max();

    bitset<size_t(max - min) + 1> had_before;

    while(first != last)
    {
        T x = *first;
        size_t i = x - min;
        if(!had_before[i])
        {
            had_before.set(i);
            *out = x;
            ++out;
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Qqqqqqqwwwww111qq1q1Qa";
    auto first = begin(s), last = end(s);
    auto new_last = remove_duplicates(first, last, first);
    for_each(first, new_last, [](char x) { cout << x; });
}
```

Output is:

```
Qqw1a
```